Prove that $n! \geq 2^{n-1}$ using combinatorics
Using a combinatorial argument, prove that $n! \geq 2^{n-1}$.
I have seen the proof using induction, but given factorial and $2^{n-1}$, I thought there might just be a combinatorial proof. But couldn't find it myself or on the internet.

This is clearly false. If anything, the reverse inequality is the correct one, except for the cases $n=1,2$ in which there is an equality.

@mark thanks for pointing out, i have corrected my question

I assume you mean $n! \ge 2^{n - 1}$. We can verify this manually for $n = 1$ so it's enough to think about $n \ge 2$.
Say you have $n$ distinguishable balls going into $n$ distinguishable bins. We consider the number of possible arrangements of the balls into the bins. We have $n$ balls that can go in the first bin, then we have $n - 1$ balls left over that we can put in the second bin, and so on until we have $2$ balls to pick to go in the $(n - 1)$th bin and a final ball which has to go into the $n$th bin. The total number of arrangements here is therefore $n \times (n - 1) \times \ldots 2 \times 1 = n!$. At each stage before the last, we have at least $2$ balls to pick from to go into each bin, so there are at least $2^{n - 1}$ choices that can be made for the first $n - 1$ bins.
I don't think this is anymore enlightening than just writing $$\overbrace{\underbrace {n}_{\ge 2} \times \underbrace {n - 1}_{\ge 2} \times \ldots \times \underbrace {3}_{\ge 2} \times 2}^{n - 1 \text { terms}} \times 1 \ge 2^{n - 1} \times 1$$
but you might prefer it.
